# HTML link to directory in a Samba share, that works on Internet Explorer 7/8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, samba, smb, cifs

I want my HTML page to link to a directory in a Samba share (protocol SMB/CIFS Windows share).
In my HREF I wrote `file://server/Share2/folder3`

Most browsers handle it fine (mount the share and open a file manager on folder3) except Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8, which say `Permission denied` without even asking for a password.
What should I write in the HREF for IE7/8 to be able to open folder3?

Notes:

It works fine if the path does **not** contain the `folder3` part.

It works fine if the share is already mounted. So before testing it, type "net use" to make sure that no share is already mounted.

The Windows username and the share username are not the same, so a popup should ask for a login/password. Again, this works fine if the path does **not** contain the `folder3` part.

Comment: Please quote that part from `smb.conf` on your Samba server that sets the properties for the `Share2` share. Also, what are the Unix file permissions for the filesystem directory where this share is hosted? (in other words: permissions for what is described by `path = ...` in smb.conf)

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for file:// links is:

```
file:///path/on/local/computer

file://server/share/folder
```

So in your case try file://server/Share2/folder3

Comment: Unfortunately, changing to the correct syntax does not change anything.
Both syntaxes (legacy and correct) lead to the same problem.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: `file://` is a **local file** protocol URI scheme, the OP asked for a samba URI, which is `smb://` or `cifs://`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes. Web browsers don't support the entire set of URI schemes, just URLs which is a simpler subset. Also you can't create a usable link with a href=smb:// scheme because that's not a registered scheme on most browsers (you probably need a browser plugin to handle it).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is fixed by adding the share to trusted sites in IE.
(Eg, internet options security, trusted sites)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I would like this to work without touching client computers, though.